# Safari 9 Key Command. Go back to previous page

Tags: macos, safari

I would like to program my Wacom tablet, thus what is the correct Safari key command to go back to the previous page?

I am using Safari 9.1.1 on Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu command to go back a page is "History" > "Back".

The command key equivalent is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

option key + left arrow also works for El Capitan.